Fastest root-finding algorithm for specific sine function
I'm trying to find an algorithm which will tell me any root of the function sin(πx)² + sin(π(323/x))². With this function I can very confidently isolate an interval in which one of these roots would exist, however there is no change in the signs in front of the function values, which is why algorithms like bisection don't work. Furthermore there are a couple of trivial roots like 1 and 323, these I'm not interested in. Is there any good algorithm to find roots on functions like these?

The solutions to the equation corresponds to $x = k_1$ and $\dfrac{323}{x} = k_2$ where $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $k_1k_2 = x\cdot \dfrac{323}{x} = 323$ therefore $k_1,k_2$ are divisors of $323$.

so $x = 1, 17, 19, 323$
